# C# MailKit - How to create a Rtf message

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'm trying to send a message in rtf format but on reception it is not interpreted correctly  by gmail, etc. (except Mail.app on MacOS).  Here is a sample code. Some client application consider it as "text".

```
String body = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;} This line is the default color\line \cf2 This line is red\line \cf1 This line is the default color}"
message.Body = new TextPart("rtf") { Text = body };
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Some email accounts are only text and will not accept RTF or HTML.  Try sending those client a RTF using outlook and see if they get RTF.

Answer (score 0):

As [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) points out, most mail clients do not support RTF.

Google mail only supports HTML and plain-text messages as far as I know.

I tried testing this by using Outlook to send an RTF message to GMail, but alas, my Exchange server always overrides the RTF by converting it to HTML and so GMail always receives text/html instead of text/rtf.

I might be able to get Outlook to send text/rtf if I configure it to send via some non-Exchange account, but I'm too lazy to bother.

Comment: I don't have outlook. GMail offers rtf text as an attachment.More precisely, before I used System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient and when I send an RTF message to GMail (without any conversion).  Gmail.com display a plain/text message but preserves the RTF which is visible as RTF in Mail.app (on macOS). So my question must be: is it possible to get the same behavior with MailKit?

Comment: Yes. All you have to do is construct the same MIME structure that the old System.Net.Mail.MailMessage had and it will work the same way. Take a look at an example message sent by System.Net.Mail and use the COntent-Type headers to figure out the tree-structure of the MIME parts and then construct a message in MimeKit using the same tree structure. If you need help, I can help you but I'll need a sample message.